# Loading PC OS from network

Tags: pc, networking

I am looking for a solution for computer workstations with fit the following points:

1. Workstation will start into a app hosted from citrix
2. Workstation will not have a OS installed on it
3. Be able to make changes to the OS and have the changes automatically rolled out to the workstations
4. Several USB devices supported by workstation and usable with citrix application
5. Wake-on-Lan
6. As little as hardware as possible (Or as cheap as possible)
7. And of course it has to be a reliable solution that could be used in a production environment.

For example, I have looked into the raspberry pi with a sort pxe setup using u-boot. Downside is then it does not support a pxe setup out of the box, so a SD card would also be needed per device. I have not yet tested it and I am not 100% sure how stable and reliable it would be, but if one device would get wrecked, it would also be really easy and cheap to have a backup ready and simply replace it.

Comment: You gave the answer to your question: You need a device to pxe-boot to a minimal os that connects to your citrix server. That is pretty much every current PC. No need for local storage in that setup.